# Is this Dictionary-based UserCache implementation thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, thread-synchronization

I have a piece of code like this:

```
public class UserCache
{
    private Dictionary<int, User> _users = new Dictionary<int, User>();

    public User GetUser(int id)
    {
        User u = null;

        lock (_users)
        {
            if (_users.containsKey(id))
                return _users[id];
        }

        //The below line is thread-safe, so no worries on that.
        u = RetrieveUser(id); // Method to retrieve from database;

        lock (_users)
        {
            _users.Add(id, u);
        }

        return u;
    }
}
```

I'm locking the access to dictionary, however someone in my team told that it's still not thread-safe (without an explanation). Question is - do you think this is thread safe at all?

Edit: Forgot to ask, what a solution would look like. Please note that I'm not looking to lock the whole method, as the retrieve user is a time consuming operation.

Comment: Looks okay to me, is it just this particular code or is there some other code that might have a problem?

Comment: Better if you use [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) - Not sure why this code is not thread-safe

Comment: You may want to make `_users` readonly as well

Comment: Idon't think  you have more choice here because the result of As

Comment: If you want the dictionary to be thread safe then why dont you just create a prop for the dictionary and lock its Set?

Comment: As a side-note, a `ConcurrentDictionary<int, Lazy<User>>` would serve you well here: `return _users.GetOrAdd(id, _ => new Lazy<User>(() => RetrieveUser(id))).Value;`. Be aware that the `User` itself is not protected. If the `User` is not immutable, you would need extra synchronization each time you read or update its properties.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it's not thread-safe. Imagine it's called twice at the same time with the same ID, which isn't previously present.

Both threads would get as far as `RetrieveUser`, and they'd *both* call `_users.Add(id, u)`. The second call would fail because the key would already exist in the dictionary.

(As an aside, I'd strongly recommend using braces for locks, if statements etc, for the sake of readability.)

Comment: Did you mean *would fail because the key would already exist in the dictionary* ?

Comment: Obviously. Also, this is known as a race condition

Comment: Ok, so what you are saying is there is chance of getting an exception since add might get called twice for the same id, and instead if I use _users[id] = u, this should be fine?

Comment: I might be wrong but I think it depends on what *thread safety* means. OP will *never* get a wrong result from the code in the question. (ignoring unnecessary db calls and exceptions)

Comment: @I4V Throwing an exception that could only ever happen in multi-threaded code probably qualifies as "not threadsafe". If the code was using `_users[id] = u` on the other hand I'd agree.

Comment: Even if you change the .Add call to a setter, you still have potential problems. In the race condition scenario, the two callers to GetUser now have two different instances of the User for the same Id. That's not a very intuitive interface for a cache. To get around this, you could re-check whether the user is present inside the second lock. If not, add your new user. If it's been added in the meantime, return the one from the cache.

Comment: @Mike: As Niall says, it depends on what you mean by "fine". Does your code rely on the same instance being returned every time, for example?

Answer (score 3):

It is threadsafe in the sense that it will not corrupt any data structures. It is not thread-safe in the sense that the entire method behaves atomically. Two threads might find the item to be missing, then create it then add it. One of the adders will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Idon't think  you have more choice here because the result of _users.Add(id,u) depend on  RetrieveUser you have to lock all method to make it thread safe. may be john skeet  can confirm  this
the solution  may  look  like  this

```
public class UserCache
 {
  private Dictionary<int, User> _users = new Dictionary<int, User>();
 private readonly object _syncLock = new object(); 
 public User GetUser(int id)
{
   User u = null;

    lock (_syncLock)
    { 

        if (_users.containsKey(id))
            return _users[id];


    //The below line is threadsafe, so no worries on that.
    u = RetrieveUser(id); // Method to retrieve from database;


        _users.Add(id, u);
    }

    return u;
}
```

}

hope this  help

Answer (score -4):

I think you must apply the singleton pattern to have a really thread safe code. In this moment you can have 2 instances of your class.

Comment: And there's absolutely *no* requirement to use singletons in order to have thread-safe code, fortunately.